# How do I direct cmd to the right place and begin installation of pygame?

Tags: python, cmd, command, pygame, python-3.5

I am tying to install pygame 3.5 to my laptop and when doing so cmd doesn't work the way I want to. I don't know how to use cmd much I only got to where I was by opening at the location in the second screen shot and typing in -m pip install pygame.

This clearly doesn't work, so I was wondering what do I type in cmd to get it work (including cd and how to get to a certain location). I need to install pygame to use on my compiler which is IDLE. I have Python 3.5.0 and I for certain reasons can't use a different version.

Here are the screenshots of what I am doing

[image: What I am doing in Command]

[image: What I have placed in file]

The way I access file is I do Shift+Right Click and Open Command Line here and just type the stuff -m... stuff mentioned above and shown in first screen shotin command line

Comment: on first screen you have typo - `pyjon` - but it should be `python`

Comment: BTW: mostly with `pip` you don't have to download `.whl` because it can download it from server automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install with pip you need to use C:...\ python -m pip install full_name_of_file.whl and pygame needs to be in the same directory as pip. At least, that has always worked for me.

Sometimes, it is easier to navigate to the folder in which pip 3.5 is and put the whl there, then run C:..\ pip install full_name_of_file.whl. You may also need to run CMD as Administrator, because it is making changes to restricted folders (depending on how your administration is set up).

Comment: Running as admin has me at Windows/system32. What do I type as commands to reach the file with the filename.whl?

Comment: The command cd C:\...\ will bring you to the location. You'll have to know what directory it (pip and the wheel file) is in and type that after cd. Then, you're going to want to type the command I showed (the one with pip install filename.whl) once you are at the location. If that answers your question.